# MySQL day-on-day totals by day of the week

Tags: mysql

My shopping cart revenue appears to vary by day of the week, with Monday and Thursday being low days, Wednesday and Saturday being high days. I would therefore like to display a web page showing totals like this:

```
Week #    Sun    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat
Week 1   $5.00  $1.00  $3.00  $9.00  $1.00  $3.00  $9.00
Week 2   $5.23  $1.07  $2.98  $8.75  $0.02  $3.14  $7.51
Week 3   etc.
```

I can query for a given day of the week like this:

```
SELECT count( id ) AS orders, 
       order_date, 
       date_format( order_date, '%a' ) AS weekday, 
       sum( total) AS revenue
FROM `ss_orders`
WHERE dayofweek( order_date ) = 1
      AND order_date >= date_add( now( ) , INTERVAL -83 DAY )
GROUP BY order_date
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

which gives me the daily totals for all Sundays in the past 12 weeks. I can therefore do 7 queries to get what I need (1 query for each day of the week). It seems like I ought to be able to get the whole thing in a single query.

What should the query be? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the corrected query from the preferred solution.

```
SELECT 
  week( o.order_date ) as WkNumber,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 6, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesSun,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 6, 1, 0 )) as OrdersSun,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 0, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesMon,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 0, 1, 0 )) as OrdersMon,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 1, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesTue,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 1, 1, 0 )) as OrdersTue,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 2, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesWed,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 2, 1, 0 )) as OrdersWed,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 3, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesThu,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 3, 1, 0 )) as OrdersThu,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 4, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesFri,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 4, 1, 0 )) as OrdersFri,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 5, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesSat,
  sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 5, 1, 0 )) as OrdersSat,
  sum( o.total ) as SalesWeek,
  sum( 1 ) as OrdersWeek
from
  ss_orders o
where
  o.order_date > date_add( now(), INTERVAL -13 WEEK )
group by
  week( o.order_date )
order by o.order_date desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are actually looking for a type of pivot table query.

```
SELECT 
      week( o.order_date ) as WkNumber,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 6, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesSun,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 6, 1, 0 ) as OrdersSun,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 0, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesMon,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 0, 1, 0 ) as OrdersMon,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 1, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesTue,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 1, 1, 0 ) as OrdersTue,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 2, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesWed,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 2, 1, 0 ) as OrdersWed,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 3, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesThu,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 3, 1, 0 ) as OrdersThu,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 4, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesFri,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 4, 1, 0 ) as OrdersFri,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 5, 1, 0 ) * o.total ) as SalesSat,
      sum( if( weekday( o.order_date ) = 5, 1, 0 ) as OrdersSat,
      sum( o.total ) as SalesWeek,
      sum( 1 ) as OrdersWeek
   from
      ss_orders o
   where
      o.order_date > date_add( now(), INTERVAL -12 WEEK )
   group by
      week( o.order_date )
```

you might have to adjust the WHERE clause to truly get 12 full weeks if you are in the middle of a week... such as changing NOW() to something like
date_add( now(), interval -weekday(now()) ), but I'd have to think more on that part.

Answer (score 2):

Group by week then day?

```
SELECT count( id ) AS orders, 
       date_format( order_date, '%a' ) AS weekday, 
       WEEK(order_date) AS week_number,
       sum( total) AS revenue
FROM 
       `ss_orders`
WHERE 
       order_date >= date_add( now( ) , INTERVAL -83 DAY )
GROUP BY 
       WEEK(orderdate), DAY(orderdata)
ORDER BY 
       order_date DESC
```

Should give you a result like this:

```
orders | weekday | week_number | revenue
5        Sun       1             20
6        Mon       1             15
...
```

Comment: Both solutions work, wish I could take both! But indeed the pivot table is what I want.